# How to scroll to comment box in Wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress

I want to find the universal way to scroll to comment box in WP powered blog.

Unfortunately I cannot use ... because sometimes its named different way.

Any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: could you explain a little further, maybe some example code would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on WordPress 3.1.2

To go directly to the first comment

```
http://example.com/path/slug/#comments
```

To go directly to the form to enter a new comment

```
http://example.com/path/slug/#respond
```

Comment: This is correct, but depending on the theme, those IDs could be different. If neither of those works, looking for id="??" in the HTML (where ?? is the name of the id near the comments section).

Comment: These are not set in the theme, but in wp-includes/comment-template.php so are common to the majority of valid themes.